# Windows Phone Marketplace

Tags: store

Is there different app marketplace for every country or region ?? Like one for US, one for UK and one for India.

If so, why has microsoft gone with this strategy rather than having just one marketplace for all. Also, are all the apps available on all markets or it depends on the developer provider.

I hated bada for the same reason and because of that only I think it shrinked. There were simply no apps in the indian market and you weren't allowed to download the apps from other market

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every country has a different marketplace and the marketplace is not available in all regions. The applications available vary from region to region.

The developer decides what regions the application can be downloaded from. This is for practical and legal reasons. For example it may not make sense for a German bus timetable application to be available Brazil or it may be illegal for the Twitter application to be available in China.

Comment: Other than the location specific or legal issues, are there any other reasons restricting the buyer from releasing an app worldwide like extra cost for uploading an international market app